# How to create a hierarchy structure in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns:

[image]

I need to create more columns based on the number of levels and based on the hierarchy.

For example:

```
Level 1
Architecture ->Level 2
             ->Asses Inventory ->level 3
                              ->Program
```

I need create three columns if there are a maximum of three levels. I have achieved this in PowerBI.

[image]

How can I achieve the same thing in SQL?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Any reason you've tagged both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: `ParentId` should be `null` if there's no higher level.

Comment: There are various ways how to solve that.  Which one to choose depends heavily on the DBMS you use, and the nature of the tree (if it is rarely changed, but often traversed, or the other way round, how you want to traverse the tree, how much entries the tree has, sorting of the children, …) without that information it is not really possible to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2):

In T-SQL I'd just join the table to itself multiple times

Create a new table how you want it then something like:

```
   INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
(LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3)
SELECT
a.name,
b.name,
c.name
FROM TABLE1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 b
ON a.category_id = b.parent_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 c
on b.category_id = c.parent_id
GO
```

That should do what you're after I think.

Comment: Other than the superfluous `GO` this will work in any database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver15) type. It comes with a lot of methods to work with the hierarchy itself like:

- GetAncestor
- GetDescendant
- GetLevel
- GetRoot
- IsDescendantOf

In your example, you will have something like this:

```
ID      Name
/1/     Architecture
/1/1/   Asses Invenctory
/1/2/   Process2
/2/     Assset Management
```